# Can airlines claim back denied boarding compensation+expenses from handling agents?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, ec261, denied-boarding

I've been denied boarding on 8 flights to the UK, due to most handling companies across Europe being misinformed about a specific detail of UK carrier regulations. easyJet and Jet2 have confirmed they know the relevant rules, so if denied boarding I send an urgent email to their respective internal operations teams who then swiftly get me to my destination and pay EU261 compensation.

It's gone so far as easyJet having had to pay EUR 2850 in compensation, PLUS expenses like food/accommodation. easyJet's customer operations manager (!) has even told me to phone/text him privately going forward if stopped at the gate so he can try to avert it, which is good as he's always been incredibly efficient and helpful.

Jet2 have so far had to pay EUR 250 in compensation.

I rarely feel sorry for big businesses with WAY more cash than me, but in this case I sort of do, since easyJet and Jet2 have explicitly confirmed we're on the same page about the relevant regulations, and yet their numpties for handling partners keep putting them in a position of liability toward me.

**My question is**: in clear-cut, unambiguous cases of being wrongfully denied boarding through the handler's fault, can the airline cash in what they pay me from the handling agent?

If anyone has knowledge of how this works, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: This sounds like a Law.SE question

Comment: Probably depends a lot on the specific wording of their contract. May also depend on how training is handled (I.e. if it’s solely done internally by the handling agent or if the airline does it or somehow participates), and possibly on how this is all described in Timatic or other tools they use. BTW, welcome back, I believe we hadn’t seen you in a while.

Comment: @jcaron TIMATIC's an absolute dog's breakfast on the relevant topic is all I can say. TIMATIC apparently had "long meetings" with the Home Office's Carriers Liaison Section in Hayes, and recently I phoned their head and constructively told him it's **still** nowhere near good enough. He didn't disagree with my explanations, but effectively revealed that they and TIMATIC struggle a lot to agree on acceptable wordings in general; in this case it caused the wording to be downright misleading. That said, my impression with most handlers is that they don't chiefly rely on Timatic for this

Comment: Is your issue that you're trying to fly to the UK with just a Swedish ID card while being a UK resident?

Comment: @JonathanReez Yep, right you are! Settled/pre-settled status doesn't come with a physical document but pops up on the screen when my ID's scanned at the border. Therefore, the Home Office has written in three carrier communications "Carriers are not currently required to check an EU, EEA or Swiss citizen’s immigration status, or confirm that they are entitled to enter the UK on a national identity card, when deciding whether to bring them to the UK. They only need to check that they have a valid passport or valid national identity card." That detail is what most handlers are clueless about.

Comment: @JonathanReez Again, easyJet's and Jet2's internal specialists know this, and as I have their contact details, they'll always sort me if bounced, and fast at that! Ryanair's Immigration Dept OTOH are as clueless as most handlers, and aggressively refuse to let themselves be proven wrong with official proof (again, NOT just with this regulation; by their fault, many Brits were also wrongfully denied boarding on flights to Schengen), hence why I only use Ryanair to the UK from CPH or SZG (where the handlers know the rules and aren't blindly loyal to the Ryanair Immigration Dept)

Answer (score -4):

Handlers are legally agents of the airline, so the airlines still bear the responsibility for their actions, as they would for any contractor/employee.

EU261 only mentions the air carrier and has no notion of 3rd parties involved.

> > For the purposes of this Regulation:
>
> (a) "air carrier" means an air transport undertaking with a valid
> operating licence;
>
> (b) "operating air carrier" means an air carrier that performs or
> intends to perform a flight under a contract with a passenger or on
> behalf of another person, legal or natural, having a contract with
> that passenger;
>
> (c) "Community carrier" means an air carrier with a valid operating
> licence granted by a Member State in accordance with the provisions of
> Council Regulation (EEC) No 2407/92 of 23 July 1992 on licensing of
> air carriers(5);
>
> (d) "tour operator" means, with the exception of an air carrier, an
> organiser within the meaning of Article 2, point 2, of Council
> Directive 90/314/EEC of 13 June 1990 on package travel, package
> holidays and package tours(6);

The airline has to fork over, and then, this will, likely, be dealt internally between the airline and the handler, respecting contracts or other policies.

Comment: The OP is asking how exactly it will be "dealt internally between the airline and the handler"

Comment: Well, this is private business between airline and handler @JohnPardon

Comment: Yes . . . so what?  Doesn't change the fact that you have not answered the question "can the airline cash in what they pay me from the handling agent?"

Comment: @NicolasFormichella What I'm essentially wondering is whether the airline, despite not actually being at fault, ultimately has to suffer the financial loss, or if they can recoup it from the handler as rightfully should be the case IMHO? If not, though, I might honestly start cutting them some slack (at least easyJet) and settle for vouchers rather than bank transfers (though now that me and easyJet's head of customer operations have agreed I'll phone/text his mobile if stopped at the gate, easyJet denials will now hopefully become less common)

Comment: @Crazydre If they can recover compensation from the handler, sure, as I said in my answer, the airline is responsible for any action done in her name. Then, nothing is legally preventing them from internally recovering it, but this is done through contracts and everything else. I don't know if that's the case in every jurisdiction, but that may warrant a Law.SE

Comment: How a company internally deals with penalties is up to the company. Whether it is legal is an entirely different matter and is specific to local employment laws. You're worried that the handler will be penalized, but the likelihood of that happening is extremely low if the airline's finance and legal department are structured properly. Case-by-case penalties are a real nightmare to deal with, especially when you deduct pay, and I'm certain there are EU laws that cover this.

Comment: @Nelson No, I'm ***hoping*** the handlers get penalised, so that the airlines that know my papers are in order won't have to suffer financially ***at the end of the day***

Comment: Obviously we don't know the details of confidential agreements between airlines and handling agents, but it is possible that someone here will know what practices are generally common in the industry when it comes to such matters.

Comment: @Crazydre another reason to hope for that outcome is that if the handlers are liable to reimburse the airline for the compensation that the airline had to pay out for the handler's error then the handler will have some motivation to make fewer mistakes, making your life easier.  If that were the case, though, the customer operations head would not be so likely to take a personal interest as it wouldn't be so costly to the airline.  Perhaps that is the answer to your question.

Comment: @phoog In May-Jul I flew with easyJet into the UK about 20 times. Seems to me (no disrespect meant) they're powerless to simply alert their handling network of the rules. Instead we implicitly agreed the immigration support would deal with my bookings individually: I'd email them my booking references for them to highlight (without replying as they're not customer-facing), then they'd email the handling agent on the day (twice I peeked at printouts the gate agents had, which said "the passenger **MUST NOT** be denied boarding). Same with Jet2, except they pick up on my bookings automatically